# Invalidating Cookies?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

While updating a project I'm working on, I never set an expiration date on the cookies/ session.  I've realized this and now have added the maxAge in `express.session`'s cookie field so they properly time out.

I'm wanting the users that have logged in the last couple days to get a new cookie that actually expires.

My plan was to remove the session data in our session store, forcing everyone to log in again.  If I do this, will this invalidate the old cookie and be replaced by a new cookie from the server with an expiration date like I'd expect?

Comment: this may be a stupid comment but why not just changing the cookie name ? session name ?

Comment: @AMS A few modules in the app rely on cookies/ sessions keys being set to a certain field.  It's not trivial to change them, so I figured it would be easier to just remove the existing sessions, assuming it reset the cookie.  Changing the cookie's secret seems to be the easiest solution, however.

Comment: @AMS You are referring to the keys the cookie/ session data is set to, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your secret key value in CookieStore, the old cookie will become invalid,

e.g:

`app.use(CookieStore({secret: 'changedkey'}))`

Comment: Well damn, way easier!  Thanks for the tip.